# Center vertically listview

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a listview and a layout that is displayed in this way:
[image]

I wish that the items were also centered vertically. How can I do? this is the code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+ListView/id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
        android:text="invisibile"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+ListView2/x"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="24dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Where is your ListView?

Comment: add this attribute for your relative layout and try `android:layout_gravity="center"`.

Answer (score 1):

> You have to create your own layout for your listview item. Soemthing
>   like this

```
  <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center" >
            <TextView
                android:id="@id/textItem"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

> Then, in your code, your going to have to do this
>
> new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.yourRowItemLayoutHere,
>   R.id.textItem, functions);

Comment: I set the layout_width to fill_parent and I put the TextView android: gravity = "center_horizontal" /> but it does not work. Visualize as before

Comment: but you are using a linear layout I need a relative layout -.-

Answer (score 1):

Hop this is helpful to you

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center_horizontal">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/videoView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. it will place the text view inside relative layout both vertically and horizontally.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/some_id"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```